# Need help getting Azure project built

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, visual-studio-2013

A client has given my company a Visual Studio project that I've told is using Azure and I've been told to get it working ("debugable") in Visual Studio.  I've not used anything with Azure before, so this is all new to me.  I downloaded the Azure SDK and have opened the project in Visual Studio.  I'm getting multiple errors when I try to rebuild it.  It looks like I'm missing .dll files.  I've searched online and can't find reference to those files.  My guess is that something related to Azure isn't installed, but I'm not sure how to find it.  Can someone take a look at the errors I'm getting and suggest what the problem is and how to fix it?

The most common errors seem to reference missing dll's like this "Scfx.Core.WebApi\bin\Debug\Scfx.Core.WebApi.dll' could not be found".

[image]

Comment: Looks like they're using C#6, and you're not on Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Thanks!  How did you know they were using C#6?  I'll need to explain that to my bosses to justify getting VS2015.

Comment: your code shows string interpolation syntax, and several errors point to using the `nameof` operator.  Both of those are C#6, and Visual Studio 2015 introduced the Roslyn compiler, which can compile C#6.  It's possible to get this to compile in VS2013 by grabbing the Roslyn dll's, but it's not very pretty.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you!  I'll work on getting Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Jonespolis and Woric: I've got the project compiling in VS2015, but it doesn't seem to be recognizing tags like <md-toolbar> and <md-button>.  It says they are not supported.  Any suggestions on what I'm missing?  I posted a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751583/how-do-i-get-angular-js-to-work-in-a-visual-studio-2015-solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your projects are not rebuilding because (as Jonesopolis said) it looks like you are using VS2013, but you need VS2015.

Once you have the correct version of Visual Studio it will probably compile, but if it does not then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490857/visual-studio-getting-error-metadata-file-xyz-could-not-be-found-after-edi%20/this%20stackoverflow%20question) for more help.

Comment: Thanks Woric and Jonespolis.  Questions: how can you tell it's using VS20015?  We don't have VS2015; anyway to get this to work in VS2013?