# How do I get Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense to recognize HTML tags?

Tags: html, angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

In trying to get angular tags to work in Visual Studio 2015 ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751583/how-do-i-get-angular-js-to-work-in-a-visual-studio-2015-solution). I'm messed up the intellisense for all tags.  For even simple tags such as div and body, I'm getting the error "element is not supported".  I've found solutions to the problem for older versions of Visual Studio ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474716/resolving-validation-element-xxxx-is-not-supported-warning-in-visual-stu), [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1205528.aspx), and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2005/04/21/410557.aspx) are just a few), but none of them have worked for me.  VS2015 doesn't seem to have the ReflectedSchemas directory that older versions had.  How do I get these basic HTML tags to not show a warning in Visual Studio 2015?

Here you can see the warnings on several tags:

[image]