# Enable New Language Features in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I've searched all over the internet for an answer to what seems to be a very basic question, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here. I'm in the process of upgrading me and my team to Visual Studio 2017, however, when I attempt to use new C# 7 language features, I get red squigglies. The code still compiles and runs; it's like the IDE isn't picking up the new features, though. I've added Microsoft.Net.Compilers via NuGet, and I still get the squigglies. I've attached a screenshot of a very contrived example for references (null value exception propagation).[image: Red Squigglies in VS 2017]

For what it's worth, I have the latest version of ReSharper installed. Also, Roslyn suggests C#7 code fixes, and they get fixed correctly, but I still have the red squigglies.

Comment: It may be a visual bug. You are not getting any exceptions right?

Comment: Sounds like a setup bug. I'd recommend you use "Report a problem" from VS2017 (in the top-right-hand corner).

Comment: svick got the right answer, but great suggestions from both of you. R# was the culprit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling c# 7 in a asp.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744689/enabling-c-sharp-7-in-a-asp-net-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest version of ReSharper (2016.3) [does not have full C# 7.0 support](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/02/17/state-union-resharper-c-7-vb-net-15-support/), so I think it's quite possible that's causing the issue.

Your code works fine for me with ReSharper 2017.1 EAP 4, including correctly marking the `throw` expression as not accessible. So you might want to try upgrading to that, if you're willing to use pre-release software.

Comment: Upgrading to R# EAP 5 fixed the issue. I mentioned R# for this very reason, but didn't want to install an EAP unless I absolutely had to. Unfortunately this is going to delay our adoption of VS2k17 though as we refuse to run R# EAP's on our dev machines. Thank you though.