# Setting C# 7 in 'web site' in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I create a new 'web site' in Visual Studio 2017.

I'm trying to use the new Tuple syntax - I enter this directly into the code behind:

```
private (string a, string b) myfunc()
{

}
```

It says you can't use the new tuple syntax in C# 5. I set this app as .net Framework 4.7

Is it possible to set website apps as C# 7? This works fine in new MVC apps but not websites.

I can't find a clear way to set the C# version in Google. Seems bizarre this isn't easier to set?!

Is using tuples / C# 7 in a web site project possible?

Comment: @hvd I don't think this is an exact duplicate because the question here is why are tuples not working in this specific situation.  The title implies just setting C# 7 as language version, but there is more to it than just that in the body of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling c# 7 in a asp.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744689/enabling-c-sharp-7-in-a-asp-net-application)

Answer (score 0):

Tuples aren't included to C# 7 by default. You need to install [System.ValueTuple nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/).

Please see from [this blog](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/tuples-csharp-7-visual-studio-2017):

> First things first, if you create a new Visual Studio 2017 Console App
>   in .NET Core to try tuples in C# 7, one must first add
>   System.ValueTuple from Nuget to experience the new enhancements.

Comment: This is wrong. The NuGet package is not required when .NET 4.7 is used, as .NET 4.7 already includes `ValueTuple`.

Comment: @hvd, if it's included, why he is getting this error?

Comment: The OP isn't getting the error that `ValueTuple` is missing, the OP is getting the error that C# 7 isn't enabled. Read the question, and the answers to the question this is a duplicate of.

Comment: I had actually seen that question - sorry forgot to reference it. it has no accepted answers. I tried the "Uninstall Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" - it wasn't installed, in installed it and it does reference language version 7. Still doesn't work. I'm already using version 2.0 compiler, I can't find the "Advanced Build Settings" dialogue - is not available in a website app - but is in an MVC app so I don't have that option.

Comment: @niico, but did you try ValueTuple nuget?

Comment: @Alex Yes I tried it - no effect and it's in 4.7 anyway which I am also using.

Comment: @niico In that case, please edit your question to include what you tried, and what happened instead. Be specific: for instance, if it still doesn't work but now fails with a different error, copy the error message. With that extra info, it's possible that your question should be reopened.