# Compile errors when using C# 7 features in new VS Studio 2017 ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I'm using VS 2017 usually for console applications. But now I have to create a new ASP.NET MVC project and found something curious.

Auto generation of getter and setter (context menu "Quick actions and refactoring < Ecapsulate field (and use property)") raise a compiling error. To give an easy example:

```
public class Person
{
    private string firstname;

    public string Firstname { get => firstname; set => firstname = value; }
}
```

Error message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: DummyASPNETMVC, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\dev\C#\DummyASPNETMVC\DummyASPNETMVC\Models\Person.cs(12,39,12,41): error CS1043: { or ; expected
1>C:\dev\C#\DummyASPNETMVC\DummyASPNETMVC\Models\Person.cs(12,39,12,41): error CS1513: } expected
1>C:\dev\C#\DummyASPNETMVC\DummyASPNETMVC\Models\Person.cs(14,2,14,2): error CS1513: } expected
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Uncomment the getter and setter will make the things working again.

I'm wondering because this works fine within a console application. Where's the difference here?

Comment: what is the c# version.. seems like a new feature

Comment: Getter & setter in lambda expression bodies exist since C# 7.0.

Comment: Make sure your target language is C# 7, from the Project properties, Build, Advanced

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to [Panagiotis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) and [Tetsuya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6378815/tetsuya-yamamoto). It was the version of c#.

As a reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744689/enabling-c-sharp-7-in-a-asp-net-application), you have to do three things:

1. Uninstall "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" via Nuget Package Manager and reinstall the newest version (currently the 1.0.4)
2. After this, update Microsoft.Net.Compilers to the newest version (currently 2.2.0)
3. Change the c# language via project "properties < build < advanced" to version 7.

done.

Comment: It seems that more recently the language version is automatically set depending on the targeted framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version.