# Razor & null propagation - not working under explicit C# 6 MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, c#-6.0

Current project:

- ASP.NET 4.6.2
- MVC 5
- Visual Studio 2015 Community v14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Installed the [CodeDOM Providers for .NET Compiler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/) nuget package via Project -> Install C# 6
- Confirmed that I do have the [compiler element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9x69bzw(v=vs.110).aspx) in my Web.Config and that it is referencing C# 6

My Razor code:

```
@if(Session["Type"]?.ToString() == "Insurance") {
  <text>policy of insurance</text>
} else if(Session["Type"]?.ToString() == "Warranty") {
  <text>policy of warranty</text>
} else {
  <text>protection policy</text>
}
```

Visual Studio explicitly flags this with an error,

> Feature 'null propagating operator' is not available in C# 5. Please
>   use language version 6 or greater.

And Visual Studio *is* explicitly using C# 6:

[image]

When I try to run the page itself, I get an error:

> CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'

which shows that it is explicitly going after the period following the question mark.

This project was explicitly started as a C# 6 project, and I am quite confused as to why it is derping back to C#5.

Another strange issue: **this is working just fine both in debug as well as on my local test setup** (I publish to the filesystem, view using local IIS), but when I upload to the server (which has many, many other C#6 sites) it craps out. This is the first razor-side quirk I have ever run across that actually throws an error this badly.

Comment: NB: The correct operator for null-coalescing is `??`, and `?.` is null-conditional operator. Since CodeDOM provider for Roslyn used there, have you either activated Copy Local option for related assemblies or setting target framework properly?

Comment: Sorry, it was late in the day, I was tired and had a headache. You are correct, I am trying to make use of the null-conditional operator. Copy Local has been set to True for `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`. The target framework was set to DotNet 4.6.2 when I first created the solution. All projects in the solution are using the same framework.

Comment: Version of framework isn't related with compiler version.

Comment: @VMAtm you will have to be a bit more clear. I have specified C# 6 in the Advanced Build window of my project properties, and I have explicitly upgraded the project itself to C#6 via the `Project -> Install C#6` menu option. C#6 usage by the compiler has been confirmed via the compiler element in the `web.config`. What else should I be doing?

Comment: I meant that you have to update either `DotNetCompilersPlatform` and `Compilers` packages and set your project to `c# 7.0`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44384196/213550

Comment: Could it be that in more recent VS/.net-versions explicit targeting has become more or less redundant? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)

Answer (score 12):

I was having a similar problem and found that I was missing the following from my Web.config file:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```