# IdentityServer4 tutorial AccountController throwing errors

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Trying to follow the QuickStart tutorials over at http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts and am working through http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html. I just ran
`iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/release/get.ps1'))`
and did not modify anything. When I build the solution I get the following:
[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(HttpContext.User is WindowsPrincipal wp)` is C# 7 feature.

You can read more here - [Pattern matching with is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is)

So, you will need to enable C# 7. [Enabling c# 7 in a asp.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744689/enabling-c-sharp-7-in-a-asp-net-application).