# C# 7.1 can't be published

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.1

I have ASP.NET Core C# web application. I made some changes that now use C# 7.1 features. I changed project version, so it compiles and runs fine. However, when I try to *publish* the project, I am getting an error:

> Feature 'default literal' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use language version 7.1 or greater.

Compile command that I see is:

```
C:...\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.compilers\2.6.1\tools\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1705,1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE;RELEASE;NETCOREAPP2_0 /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /warnaserror+:NU1605`
```

As suggested elsewhere, I installed `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` (v2.6.1), but it didn't make any difference.

Is there a Visual Studio setting that affects publish specifically?

**UPDATE**: Looks like a console application doesn't have this problem. If it builds successfully, it publishes successfully as well. However, the web application *does not publish*. Was anybody successful in publishing ASP.NET Core web application with C# 7.1 features?

Comment: `Project -> Project Properties (bottom) -> Build -> Advanced -> Language Version`. Change to `minor version (latest)` or `C# 7.1`

Comment: But I wonder how did you code without that setting? o_O

Comment: Thank you. As I said, **I changed project version, so it compiles and runs fine**. But even with this change it doesn't publish (I should have said *language version* for better clarity)

Comment: @Felix, I just created a sample ASP.NET Core application, that uses the C#7.1 default literal, and published it to a folder, using both Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 and dotnet CLI - no errors. Could you maybe share your sample app with the problem?

Comment: Thank you @ironstone13. I scaffolded ASP.NET Core Web application as well; then added a single line in Home controller `int x = HttpContext.Items?.Count ?? default;` and changed language to 7.1 (also tried 7.2, or latest - no difference). It compiles, but doesn't publish. I uploaded to https://github.com/virshu/SOExample But good news - it **does** publish with dotnet CLI. The only difference I see is that I have VS Community and you have Enterprise; so maybe the difference is indeed in the version of VS

Comment: @Felix, I've cloned your repo, and I can build, publish and run the web app without any issues. It looks like an environment configuration issue to me. Your publish is using a different path to `csc.exe` then mine. I've uploaded my Visual Studio configuration details, as well as publish logs to Gist - maybe that can help you https://gist.github.com/oleh-zheleznyak/458230bb535366c378fc3b7380fbc2bf

Comment: thank you. I saw the difference in the path; strangely, the path to CLI app is the same as to Web App and it publishes fine. Whatever it is, publishing through `dotnet cli` is acceptable workaround, and in line with scripting deployment, anyway!

Comment: FYI, I had this issue with .NET Framework, and the fix widely reported here did not help.  The real problem was that my ASP.NET MVC application was targeting "Any CPU", while a referenced DLL was targeting x86.  Once I adjusted the targeting to match, this extremely frustrating problem disappeared.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Adding `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` to your .pubxml file made it possible for Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.2 in my case) to publish.

Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/166543/view.html

Comment: This is exactly the miracle switch that I was looking for!

Comment: In case someone is running this on the Mac version of Visual Studio, I was unable to find a .pubxml file or the configuration option mentioned in @ironstone13 's answer below. 

All I had to do was add `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` under the `<PropertyGroup>` tags in my .csproj file and it got rid of this error!

Visual Studio for Mac V 8.0.2

Comment: Updated to 8.2 and the problem is fixed. Didn't need to add LangVersion.

Comment: I don't get it. I just updated today to 15.9.20 in VS2017. Still an issue for me. However, the above fix does work

Answer (score 50):

**Update:**
After upgrading my VS2017 from version 15.4.5 to 15.5.2 I can reproduce the problem, and I get an error

> Feature 'default literal' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use
>   language version 7.1 or greater

**The answer from @Jeremy Cook solves the issue:**
`<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` in .pubxml

---

In both old and new project formats the `LangVersion` element in project file is responsible for this.
You can either change that via `csproj` xml file or via UI in visual studio.

Please note that this setting is dependent on your **build configuration**.
To make sure that you can **both code and publish** using C# 7.1 and later make sure you configure this setting regardless of build configuration (`Debug`, `Release` etc).

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. As I said, **I changed project version, so it compiles and runs fine**. But even with this change it doesn't publish. (I should have said *language version* for better clarity)

Comment: @Felix, did you set C#7.1 for `Debug` and `Release` configurations? You probably code in `Debug` but publish in `Release`

Comment: just doublechecked; both release and debug are set up to C# 7.2 (or tried latest minor version as well)

Comment: @Felix, I will try to reproduce later today and will get back to you

Comment: @Felix I see you marked this answer as solving your problem, but your comments seem to indicate that it isn't actually working for you.  Did this actually fix your problem?

Comment: It didn't; but @ironstone13 did amazing analysis and put the answer in the comments to original question

Comment: Good that you got your problem solved and you're certainly free to accept any answer you wish as the "one that answered your question" but keep in mind future visitors, that will now end up with the same conclusion you had, they did everything this answer told them to but they still cannot publish. As such the answer does *not* in fact answer your question.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, you are totally right - after the hint from Jeremy Cook I could finally repro the problem, so I updated my answer, and up-voted his answer. Now SO users will find the solution they look for!

Comment: @ironstone13 I've simplified and improved your configuration to work with latest minor version (e.g. 7.2, 7.3 etc), don't you mind?

Comment: The note to switch to "All Configurations" was key for me! I was apparently changing the wrong one and couldn't get it to build even after following many other guides.

Answer (score 2):

For MAC users, I did spend a long time finding out. Here's what has worked for me.
Right-click to your main .csproj file and click 'Edit Project File' to open it.
Then, inside the ... add the line latest and save it.
That's it!
Run your code and it should work ok from now on.
[image: add 'latest langversion' to visual studio]

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating from ASP.NET Core 2.0 to ASP.NET Core 2.1 make sure you have line

```xml
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

in your `.pubxml` file.

Answer (score -3):

It seems you are published to your local Nuget store.  Ensure that the Nuget store is configured to use C#7.1.  And also check whether your Nuget.exe pack is updated to the latest that can use C#7.1

Comment: why do you make this conclusion? It's certainly not my intent; the target location shows as bin\Release\PublishOutput; and when I don't have 7.1 features in the code - it's exactly where the output is.