# MSB4184, VS code[Codium], Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, ASP.NET Core Projectg

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm doing a ASP.NET Core project and in VS code problems tab, I get a error:

> The expression ""Program.cs".GetPathsOfAllDirectoriesAbove()" cannot be evaluated. System.String.GetPathsOfAllDirectoriesAbove /home/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/Project/EmployeeManagment.csproj(MSB4184)[60,27]

EmployeeManagment.csproject

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Using SDK .NET Core SDK (3.1.100)

I try to find any solution in web related to my issue, but no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GetPathsOfAllDirectoriesAbove() cannot be evaluated after updating .Net Framework version (4.6.2 to 4.7.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276192/getpathsofalldirectoriesabove-cannot-be-evaluated-after-updating-net-framewor)

Answer (score 0):

If someone encountered the same problem, I accidentally managed to solve this mistake.
During compilation I had MyCurrentProjectName.csproject file window open.
It was enough to close the window and recompile the whole project.

Please note that this concerns VS insider/VS code and not Visual Studio Comunity, etc.