# MsBuild fails on Azure thus failing deployments on App Service using GitHub/Azure DevOps

Tags: github, azure-devops, msbuild, .net-4.7.2, azure-appservice

I have an app that runs locally using the test-webserver (xsp) in visual studio 2019 for mac.

I have setup the azure app service to deploy from a branch in the repository in github (via deployment center).

When it runs the deployment I get the following error:

```
D:\home\site\repository\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.3.6.0\tools\Microsoft.Managed.Core.targets(60,27): error MSB4184: The expression ""AllowCrossSiteAttribute.cs".GetPathsOfAllDirectoriesAbove()" cannot be evaluated. Method 'System.String.GetPathsOfAllDirectoriesAbove' not found. [D:\home\site\repository\Fx\Fx.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
```

I have tried to remove the Microsoft.Compiler package as per another stackoverflow question [GetPathsOfAllDirectoriesAbove() cannot be evaluated after updating .Net Framework version (4.6.2 to 4.7.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276192/getpathsofalldirectoriesabove-cannot-be-evaluated-after-updating-net-framewor) but to no avail.

Is there a way to replicate the failing msbuild step locally?

Or another workaround for the error?

Comment: Even I ran into the same issue, installed the latest for both ```Microsoft.Net.Compilers``` and `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`

Comment: hi @FelixHj, have you found a solution ?

Comment: @fatalica no I'm afraid not. I no longer have access to that system either.