# Switch. case var b when b.Contains("SomeString"): Won't compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.7

I have a Web app that is targeting .Net 4.7 and had an if/else block to see if an incoming message contains a particular string. Ugly, I wanted to use a switch statement instead like so and like I did in another project, a windows service targeting .Net 4.5.2 that compiles and works:

```
switch (message)
{
    case "SomeString":
    ...
    break;

    case var b when b.Contains("AnotherString"):  // problem line
    ....
    break;
}
```

But in the WebApp in question I get syntax errors upon build as if I'm not using C# 7.x as these, all pointing to the:

**case var b when b.Contains("AnotherString"):**

line:

```
Error   CS1002  ; expected
Error   CS1002  ; expected
Error   CS1003  Syntax error, ':' expected
Error   CS1513  } expected
```

The Crazy thing is that the Windows Service is targeting .Net 4.5.2 yet if accepts that line builds and and runs.
Google says your C# version is predicated on what .Net version you are targeting.

What the actual frick?

Backed the Web App .Net 4.5.2 as is in the service project, but that did not change anything.
Also changed the C# from "Latest major version" to 7.0 but got a different error that is a whole nuther group of google rabbit holes.

**Update** I am using VS2017 - when I add `<LangVersion>7</Langversion>` to my .csproj or if I set the C# language version to 7 in the Visual Studio Build Settings GUI, I get the following error:

> Error CS1617 Invalid option '7' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to 6.

This is the google rabbit hole error I spoke of but could not recall or fix.

Hey! There, I fixed it! My csproj file had yet references to DotNetCompliers 1.0.0. Right next to the reference for 4.2.0 (latest at the time of this writing) So I deleted that 1.0.0 refenrence. After that the debug session would not start because project/bin/roslyn/csc could not be found so I copied the folder over from another project. after doing that, I then got the complaint that "latest" for the langVersion had to be 1-6. So I set it to 7 - no go as before, crestfallen, I set it to 6 and then it worked! c# 7 features and all! it builds and runs and the switch case var b when b.Contains("string") works also In addition to that I can use other c#7 features too now.

That sucked. Now me so happy! Thanks everyone!

Comment: I don't see how that can work, as you are declaring `b` at the same time as testing to see if it contains some value. You need `b` to exist before the `switch` statement. See the section headed *Case guards* at [if and switch statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement).

Comment: You can add a `<LangVersion>version</LangVersion>` tag to a property group in *.csproj where "version" is e.g. `7.3` or versions up to `12.0` (as I am writing this) or the word `latest`. See [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version).

Comment: @OldBoy, `var b` is a [`var` pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#var-pattern) which matches any expression, including null, and assigns its result to a new local variable.

Comment: i think that feature came with c# 8

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thank you, I just found the MSDN documentation that details it.

Comment: @OldBoy. Pattern matching in case labels of switch-statements were introduced in C#7.0 with the type pattern along with the `when` clause (case guards). More patterns were introduced in later versions. See also: [The history of C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history). The link in my previous comment lists all the patterns of pattern matching. This makes the C# switch-statement even more powerful as was the VB Select-Case-statement which allowed relational conditions. And C# also introduced a switch-expression.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thank you. I need to spend some time studying again.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - you're right, it was [C# 7.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20181005045118/https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching) not 8.0.  MSFT's current doc isn't clear as to exactly when various pattern matching features were added so I used the wayback machine to check the [pattern matching docs from 2018](https://web.archive.org/web/20181117221146/https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#var-declarations-in-case-expressions) and `case var o when (o?.Trim().Length ?? 0) == 0:` is clearly shown.

Comment: @id10t - Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] that includes the following information: 1) Your visual studio version.  2) The .NET Framework version of the failing project.  3) The `.csproj` for the failing project showing compiler options including [`<LangVersion>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#langversion). ...

Comment: ... 4) Screen shots of your VS project properties including [target framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview) and [language version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61434436)?  Thanks!  Just guessing here but you may not be building with C# 7.3.

Comment: VS2017 - when I do <LangVersion>7</Langversion> If get this which is the same error I get if I set it in the GUI also. This is the google rabbit hole error I spoke of but could not recall or fix.

Error CS1617 Invalid option '7' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to 6.

Comment: Looks like VS2017 is requiring an old version of C# for your project, which is why you cannot use C# 7 language features.  I bet if you were to start a fresh, new project of the same type, you would not have this problem.  You may need to live with writing in an older C# style or try the various options from [Invalid option '7.3' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62858965) and/or [Enabling c# 7 in a asp.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42744689).

Comment: Hey! There, I fixed it!

Comment: Do not put "solved" in a title.  If the issue has been resolved, it should come as an accepted answer.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-does-stack-overflow-discourage-adding-solved-to-question-titles

Comment: @id10t - it's great you found a solution!  Rather than editing the solution into your question, please add a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so others can find it.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a reputation > 15 so I can't self-answer.