# Project compiles always but rarely gets successfully published to IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET5 solution which I publish to a local IIS. I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.4). The solution consists of a number of projects (NET5 and NetStandard2.0).

The project compiles successfully, but when I try to publish it I get the following error one  any number of random project within the solution:

> Error CS0006  Metadata file 'C:..{file}.dll' could not be found

I clean the solution, restart VS multiple times, also delete all `bin` and `obj` folders. This problem hast started since I updated VS some 3 or 4 updates.

Once in a while the main project gets published successfully.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is your problem a case of this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44258162/4800344

Comment: Can this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490247/csc-error-cs0006-metadata-file-could-not-be-found-building-a-net-3-5-applicatio) help you?

Comment: No. The solution always compiles successfully. Publishing however results in the above error for multiple projects.

Comment: Are there any details can be shared here? As you know that this kind of seldom successful actions are always weird.